# How to keep root of cloth simulation anchored to bone?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

[image]
Trying to get the leaves of this plant to shake/bend in response to armature animation. Tried adding rigid and soft bodies plus cloth; the cloth by itself falls due to gravity and seems unaffected by the armature.

Target idea is to set parent of leaves to certain bones in the armature; then use cloth animations so the leaves sway back and forth in a stylized but "realistically-inspired" manner.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: So what method do you want to use, soft body or cloth? You need to determine a vertex group that will be your pin group so that it stays hanged to the armature at its base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your leaves a cloth simulation, you need to give them a vertex group that will be the pin group (part of the object that won't be affected by the simulation). Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: that did it! Thanks!